# Not able to select the 2nd row in a webtable usng description lanugauge in UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I have written the below piece of code to pick a row from web table to process it. The code picks/opens the first row successfully, however, when it is trying to double click the second row, it errors out with an error "Unspecified error". The web table has 7 rows, nevertheless, it is failing. Can some one point out what could be the reason for the failure please?

```
Set objDesc = Description.Create
objDesc("micclass").Value = "WebTable"
objDesc("html tag").Value = "Table"
Set objList = Browser("3 - Employee Assign Benefits").Page("3 - Employee Assign Benefits").Frame("APPFRAMEWORK").ChildObjects(objDesc)
oCount = objList.Count
For k =0 To oCount - 1
    colName = objList(k).GetRoproperty("cols")
    If Trim(colName) = 21 Then 'This is the right table
        objList(k).Highlight
        rows= objList(k).GetROProperty("rows")
        For i = 1 To rows
            x = objList(k).ChildItem(i,1,"WebElement",0).GetROProperty("abs_x")
            y = objList(k).ChildItem(i,1,"WebElement",0).GetROProperty("abs_y") 
            Wait(2)
            Set obj = CreateObject("Mercury.DeviceReplay")
            obj.MouseDblClick x,y,LEFT_MOUSE_BUTTON
            Call ClickVerifyElement(Browser("3 - Employee Assign Benefits").Page("3 - Employee Assign Benefits").Frame("APPFRAMEWORK").WebEdit("ben_elig_dte"), "ben_elig_dte", "WebEdit", Parameter("elig_date"))
            Call ClickVerifyElement(Browser("3 - Employee Assign Benefits").Page("3 - Employee Assign Benefits").Frame("APPFRAMEWORK").WebList("emp_state_withd_opt_decode"), "emp_state_withd_opt_decode", "WebList", Parameter("withhold_ind"))
            Browser("3 - Employee Assign Benefits").Page("3 - Employee Assign Benefits").Frame("APPFRAMEWORK").WebButton("Save").Click
        Next
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: what are the values of `x` and `y` at the point of failure?  Have you defined `LEFT_MOUSE_BUTTON` anywhere to have a value referring to the left mouse button?  Have you ensured that every row has a `WebElement` in it that you can get the `x` and `y` values from?

Comment: Yes, every row has a web element in it. I hard coded it as below instead of parameterizing the values. In that case, code opens the mentioned row properly without any issues.
  
x = objList(k).ChildItem(2,1,"WebElement",0).GetROProperty("abs_x")
y = objList(k).ChildItem(2,1,"WebElement",0).GetROProperty("abs_y")

Even during parameterization, code is able to pick the value during the first iteration of the for loop, and getting failed in the subsequent iteration only.

Comment: Given that after you double click the first row element you are then running this `ClickVerifyElement` function followed by a `Save` click, I'd say it's likely that `objList` is effectively out of scope after the first row is actioned, due to some change or other.  Pause the script after the first click and see if the collection is still valid and still refers correctly to your list of tables.